# ¿Cómo puedo agregar o hacer gráficas con doble eje en GGPLOT2?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, gráficas

muy buen día.

Mis datos son los siguientes:
`capinfl<- data.frame(capinst=c(79.9,79.1,81.1,79.2,80.5,80.2,78.7,80.4,79.1,80.8,80.1,78.2,78.8,78.6,79.1,80.2,79.9,79.9,79.1,79.7),infla=c(3.8,3.9,4.0,3.8,3.8,3.8,4.0,3.9,3.7,3.6,3.8,3.6,3.6,4.1,4.4,4.7,5.0,5.1,5.3,5.2))`

Como se pueden dar cuenta, capinst tiene valores mas altos que infla, entonces al momento de gráficar, la escala sale muy desigual.

En excel, la grafica que buscamos sería mas o menos así. Si bien, no se puede en R, ¿que gráfico me recomendarían para completar un análisis similar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Los datos del código, son solo una parte de los que se usaron en la gráfica de Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlos Alberto, 
en general no se recomienda poner hacer gráfico en un mismo panel con dos escalas. Son propensos a la mala interpretación. Por ejemplo, prestar atención a los cruces de las líneas que no deberían cruzarse en escala natural e inferir algo a partir de ahí. Por ese (buen) motivo la librería de gráficos `ggplot::` hace prácticamente imposible usar dos escalas al mismo tiempo.

Una opción honorable es graficar cada serie en un panel con su propia escala. La interpretación esta menos sesgada, pero como cada línea queda en su propia escala se visualizan mejor las inflexiones.

Va código para hacer una versión con tus datos:

```
library(tidyverse) #Para gráficos y manipulación
library(lubridate) #Para crear la secuencia de fechas

capinfl<- data.frame(capinst=c(79.9,79.1,81.1,79.2,80.5,80.2,78.7,80.4,79.1,80.8,80.1,78.2,78.8,78.6,79.1,80.2,79.9,79.9,79.1,79.7),
                     infla=c(3.8,3.9,4.0,3.8,3.8,3.8,4.0,3.9,3.7,3.6,3.8,3.6,3.6,4.1,4.4,4.7,5.0,5.1,5.3,5.2), 
                     fecha = seq.Date(ymd("2007-01-01"), ymd("2017-09-01"), length.out = 20)) #Agrego 20 fechas que faltaban.
capinfl %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = value, -fecha) %>%   #Alargo a pares de clave-valor, servirá para tener una sola estructura de datos divisible en dos grupos
  ggplot(aes(x=fecha, y = value, group = 1)) +   
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~key,                               #Variable para el gráfico por paneles
             scales = "free",                    #Para que cada panel tenga su propia escala
             ncol = 1) +                         #Para alinear verticalmente los paneles
  theme_minimal() +                              #Fondo blanco
  scale_x_date(breaks = capinfl$fecha) +         #Una etiqueta por día
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 90,     #Rotar 90 grados la etiqueta
                                 size = 6)) +    #Achicar el tamaño de la letra
  labs(y = NULL)                                 #Eliminar etiqueta redundante (ya está en el título de panel)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede seguir trabajando para agregar mejores títulos, proporcionar mejor los espacios, etc. Pero esta es la base.

Una alternativa sería escalar las variables (entre 0-1, percentiles, etc.). Personalmente creo que los paneles son el mejor balance entre inteligibilidad del gráfico y fidelidad a los datos.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu tiempo y tu respuesta mpaladino, justo es la respuesta que esperaba, ya que el análisis que buscamos es observar como se comportan las series ante el mismo evento en el tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Al ver la pregunta, si se omitiera las escalas y los valores de los ejes Y -no sus nombres-, pareciera que se quiere encontrar una especie de relación o correlación entre las dos series.

Si bien puede ser válido, hay que tener presente que correlación no siempre va de la mano con la causa. Esto le pasó al proyecto ***google flu***, incluso hay un artículo en la revista ***science*** que habla al respecto [The Parable of Google Flu: Traps in Big Data Analysis](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/343/6176/1203.full)

Sobre lo anterior, también es posible acceder a muchos ejemplos reales en la página [spurious correlations](http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations)

Lo anterior quiere decir que, una variable de interés sólo puede ser modela a partir de otras variables subyacentes, siempre y cuando estas últimas sean independientes y la primera dependiente de las mismas.

Expuesto lo anterior existe una biblioteca `latticeExtra`, se generan los datos:

```
dias <-100
capinst<-rnorm(dias, mean=80, sd=10)
infla<-rweibull(dias, shape=1, scale=0.75)
index <- 1:dias

capinfl<- data.frame(
    capinst=capinst,
    infla=infla,
    index = index
    )
```

Se genera el gráfico con las dos series

```
library(latticeExtra)
# se puede mostrar las dos variables en el mismo tiempo
xyplot(capinst + infla ~ index, capinfl, type="l")

# se agrega dos ejes Y
# se construye cada serie por separado
obj1 <- xyplot(capinst  ~ index, capinfl, type = "l" , lwd=2, ylab="capinst",  xlab="xDías")
obj2 <- xyplot(infla ~ index, capinfl, type = "l", lwd=2, ylab="inflacion")

# --> se realiza la grafica con el segundo eje Y
doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.ylab2 = TRUE)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como gráfico interno de trabajo lo veo adecuado pero si va en un informe final o digamos mediante una implementación con Shiny para visualizarlo de forma dinámica en una Web App tomaría las palabras @mpaladino, podría desorientar al usuario que lo va leer.

No obstante hay un caso que encontré dónde si es válido aplicar un gráfico como el que buscan, -humedad relativa para termodinámica- está incluso el código para lograrlo con `ggplot2`, sólo tendrían que hallar el factor de escala (en el ejemplo está con 5) que se adecue a sus necesidades.

[ggplot2 version 2.2.0 - Demonstration of dual y-axes using sec.axis](https://rpubs.com/MarkusLoew/226759)

Aquí una sugerencia de como hallar ese factor de escala

```
library(ggplot2)
# Mostrando la serie capinst 
p <- ggplot(capinfl, aes(x = index))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = capinst), colour="blue")


# como capinst tiene una escala mayor que infla se
# requiere ajustar los datos
sf<-max(capinst)/max(infla)

# Se agrega infla a Y multiplicada por el factor
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = infla*sf), colour="red")

p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*sf, name = "Inflación Escalada"))
p <- p + labs(y = "Capinst",
              x = "xFechas",
              colour = "Parameter")
p <- p + theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9))
p
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si observan el Eje Y secundario (Inflación Escalada) apareceré la situación que se reflejaría en el `Shiny` si nos situamos en cada punto de la serie roja (inflación)

Comment: De verdad agradezco mucho tu tiempo y tu respuesta. Justo el análisis que buscamos es ver como se comportan 2 variables a lo largo del tiempo y precisamente, de manera empírica, el comportamiento de las mismas. Muchas gracias de nuevo por tu aporte.