# Dos varibales "y" en un ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Buen día, 
Tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
Fuerza q_CENAMEP   U_C q_IDIC   U_I     En X7   
   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>
1    300     0.183  0.18   0.33  0.19 -0.580 NA   
2    600     0.266  0.19   0.43  0.16 -0.66  NA   
3    900     0.285  0.2    0.37  0.16 -0.35  NA   
4   1200     0.274  0.18   0.35  0.16 -0.290 NA   
5   1500     0.269  0.18   0.38  0.16 -0.46  NA   
6   1800     0.282  0.18   0.34  0.15 -0.23  NA   
7   2100     0.278  0.18   0.34  0.15 -0.28  NA   
8   2400     0.277  0.18   0.31  0.13 -0.15  NA   
9   2700     0.278  0.18   0.22  0.13  0.27  NA
```

Quisiera graficar `q_CE` y `q_I` en función de la fuerza en un solo gráfico de `ggplot`, es posible o tengo que cambiar de libraría?.

Comment: Posible duplicada https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/241006/47366

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo sencillo:
df:

```
  Fuerza q_CENAMEP  U_C q_IDIC  U_I En.X7  X X.1 X.2 X.3
1    300     0.183 0.18   0.33 0.19 -0.58 NA  NA  NA  NA
2    600     0.266 0.19   0.43 0.16 -0.66 NA  NA  NA  NA
3    900     0.285 0.20   0.37 0.16 -0.35 NA  NA  NA  NA
4   1200     0.274 0.18   0.35 0.16 -0.29 NA  NA  NA  NA
5   1500     0.269 0.18   0.38 0.16 -0.46 NA  NA  NA  NA
6   1800     0.282 0.18   0.34 0.15 -0.23 NA  NA  NA  NA
7   2100     0.278 0.18   0.34 0.15 -0.28 NA  NA  NA  NA
8   2400     0.277 0.18   0.31 0.13 -0.15 NA  NA  NA  NA
9   2700     0.278 0.18   0.22 0.13  0.27 NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Codigo:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(p)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Fuerza,y=q_CENAMEP),color="red")+
  geom_point(aes(x=Fuerza,y=q_IDIC),color="navyblue")
```

[image: Gráfica]
Es un gráfico muy sencillo, si quieres lineas cambia el geom_point por geom_line, y luego mediante themes() puedes ajustar la leyenda, y el aspecto.

**EDIT:**

```
ggplot(p)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Fuerza,y=q_CENAMEP,color="Q_CENAMEP"),size=1)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Fuerza,y=q_IDIC,color="Q_IDIC"),size=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0,0.5))+ ylab("Q")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from=0,to=3000,by=300))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.line = element_line(color="black"))
```

Un ejemplo algo más complejo :)
[image: Gráfia más compleja]