# Corrección de gráfico en ggplot2 con 2 Ejes Y

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy graficando las ventas y los beneficios de una empresa haciendo uso de dos ejes y en ggplot2. El problema yace cuando se gráfica y la línea de beneficio es a veces mayor que la de ventas, lo que no tiene sentido. He querido modificar el eje y secundario con distintos breaks pero no me ha dado resultado.

```
    datos %>% 
filter(Año == "2018") %>% group_by(Mes) %>%
  summarise(Ventas = round(sum(Total)),
            Beneficio = round(sum(Ganancia))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(Mes)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Ventas, group = 1, color = "Ventas"), size = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Beneficio*10, group = 1, color = "Beneficio"), size = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Ventas",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ ./10, name = "Beneficio")) +
  labs(color = "", 
       title = "Ventas vs. Beneficios", 
       fill = "") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom")
```

Esta imagen es la que obtengo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la que quiero replicar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241006/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-agregar-o-hacer-gr%c3%a1ficas-con-doble-eje-en-ggplot2